# How can I convert a LazySeq of Characters to a String in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, types, primitive-types, coercion

Let's say I have a **LazySeq** of *java.lang.Character* like

```
(\b \ \! \/ \b \ \% \1 \9 \/ \. \i \% \$ \i \space \^@)
```

How can I convert this to a String? I've tried the obvious

```
(String. my-char-seq)
```

but it throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class java.lang.String (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
[Thrown class clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException]
```

I think because the String constructor expects a primitive **char[]** instead of a **LazySeq**. So then I tried something like

```
(String. (into-array my-char-seq))
```

but it throws the same exception. The problem now is that **into-array** is returning a **java.lang.Character[]** instead of a primitive **char[]**. This is frustrating, because I actually generate my character sequence like this

```
(map #(char (Integer. %)) seq-of-ascii-ints)
```

Basically I have a seq of ints representing ASCII characters; 65 = A, etc. You can see I explicitly use the primitive type coercion function **(char x)**.

What this means is that my **map** function is returning a primitive **char** but the Clojure **map** function overall is returning the *java.lang.Character* object.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

This works:

```
(apply str my-char-seq)
```

Basically, *str* calls toString() on each of its args and then concatenates them. Here we are using *apply* to pass the characters in the sequence as args to *str*.

Answer (score 16):

Another way is to use `clojure.string/join`, as follows:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str] )
(assert (= (vec "abcd")                [\a \b \c \d] ))
(assert (= (str/join  (vec "abcd"))    "abcd" ))
(assert (= (apply str (vec "abcd"))    "abcd" ))
```

There is an alternate form of `clojure.string/join` which accepts a separator.  See:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/join

For more complicated problems, you may also wish to lookat `strcat` [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo):

```
(require '[tupelo.core :as t] )
(prn (t/strcat "I " [ \h \a nil \v [\e \space (byte-array [97])
                  [ nil 32 "complicated" (Math/pow 2 5) '( "str" nil "ing") ]]] ))
;=> "I have a complicated string"
```

Answer (score 11):

As a special case, if the underlying type of the sequence in question is `clojure.lang.StringSeq` you can also do:

```
(.s (my-seq))
```

which is extremely performant as it is just pulling out the public final CharSequence field from the clojure StringSeq class.

Example:

```
(type (seq "foo"))
=> clojure.lang.StringSeq

(.s (seq "foo"))
=> "foo"

(type (.s (seq "foo")))
=> java.lang.String
```

an example of the timing implications (and note the difference when using a type hint):

```
(time 
  (let [q (seq "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]
    (dotimes [_ 1000000]
      (apply str q))))
"Elapsed time: 620.943971 msecs"
=> nil

(time 
  (let [q (seq "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]
    (dotimes [_ 1000000]
      (.s q))))
"Elapsed time: 1232.119319 msecs"
=> nil

(time 
  (let [^StringSeq q (seq "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]
    (dotimes [_ 1000000]
      (.s q))))
"Elapsed time: 3.339613 msecs"
=> nil
```